# Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, command-prompt, messagebox

I have a Visual Studio 2015 program that calls a command prompt. How do I write 2 lines to the command prompt? This is my current code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    startInfo.Arguments = "/C copy " + calibrT1 + "_CDF.hex\"" + calibrT1 + "_ECC_CDF.hex\"";
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();
 startInfo.Arguments = "/C c:\\ti\\hercules\\nowECC\\2.21.00\\nowECC -f035 -r4 -i "+ calibrT1 + "_ECC_CDF.hex\" -a ";
                    //MessageBox.Show("Tester");
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();
```

As an interesting note. This current code does not work. However if the  MessageBox.Show("Tester") is not commented out it does work. As such I can determine my lines of code are correct and work as I wish, however do not work sequentially without the MessageBox. I can't work out why as I can see no logical reason why a message box should effect my command prompt.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Before starting the new one, wait for the previous to finish: add
                    process.WaitForExit(); between .Start() and the new arguments.

Comment: the messagebox would have made it wait before you tried running the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait before starting the new one. So need to put WaitForExit before (this does the job that the MessageBox was doing).

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C copy " + calibrT1 + "_CDF.hex\"" + calibrT1 + "_ECC_CDF.hex\"";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start(); 
process.WaitForExit(); // Wait First                       
startInfo.Arguments = "/C c:\\ti\\hercules\\nowECC\\2.21.00\\nowECC -f035 -r4 -i "+ calibrT1 + "_ECC_CDF.hex\" -a ";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I was missing :)